# What is the purpose of OpenWithProgIds registry key?

Tags: windows, windows-10, registry, windows-shell, file-association

I have read through many Stack Overflow questions as well all related Microsoft documentation I could find, however, I couldn't discover an exact answer.

I'm registering my program as a default application for a specific extension in Windows 10. I added the following entries to the registry:

- `HKCU\Software\Classes\my-program.ext`
- `HKCU\Software\Classes\.ext\(Default)` = `my-program.ext`
- `HKCU\Software\Classes\.ext\OpenWithProgIds\my-program.ext`

*Everything works fine, the association is successfully created.*

However, **I don't understand the purpose of the `OpenWithProgIds`**. I thought it represents the list of alternative applications for this extension, however, even without adding `my-program.ext` to `OpenWithProgIds` my program is still present in the "Open With" list **as well as all the previous applications** registered through `.ext\(Default)`.

Seems that there is some kind of cache containing all the previously associated programs for a specific extension. But if so, why do we need `OpenWithProgIds` at all? Probably this behavior was introduced in Windows 10, and the `OpenWithProgIds` is considered obsolete.

I would be grateful for any thoughts or clarifications.

Comment: Yes, Explorer keys a cache in another key. OpenWithProgIds is the documented key ISVs should use.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/specifying-file-handlers-for-file-name-extensions), the purpose of the `OpenWithProgIDs` subkey is to provide a better experience for the user.

Excerpt:

> You can register different applications that are able to open a particular file extension by adding versioned ProgIDs as values to the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT<*extension*>\OpenWithProgids key. This registry key contains a list of alternate ProgIDs associated with the file extension. The applications associated with the listed ProgIDs appear in the **Open With** *Product Name* submenu. If the same application is specified in both the `OpenWithList` and `OpenWithProgids` keys, the operating system merges the duplicates.

Comment: But what is the difference then between the default entry and the one in \OpenWithProgids\ ?  I (falsely) thought that OpenWithProgids only provided the 'open with' functionality, however, when the default key is absent, OpenWithProgids takes over entirely (double click, icon etc.).  I wanted to NOT associate (double click and icon etc.) yet still tell Windows it can use the app (e.g. Open With).  When no double click/icon association is wanted it appears one can NOT use OpenWithProgids either

Answer (score 0):

According to this article [Specifying File Handlers for File Name Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/specifying-file-handlers-for-file-name-extensions?view=vs-2022)
:

> The OpenWithProgids key is only supported in Windows XP. Because other operating systems ignore this key, do not use it as the only registration for file handlers. Use this key to provide a better user experience in Windows XP.